# How to prevent a user from creating GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In GCP, any user is able to create a project. An organisation may end up having a lot of projects in its hierarchy.

How to we disable all the users from being able to create projects, and only allow a few authorized to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Permissions are [inherited from the top](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control), in this case from the [organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#setting-up):

> By default, when the organization is created your entire domain is granted Project Creator and Billing Account Creator IAM roles at the organization level. This ensures that users in your domain will be able to continue creating projects as they did before and no disruption occurs.
>
> The Organization Administrator will decide when they want to start actively using the organization. They can then change the default permissions and enforce more restrictive policies as needed.

In [Using Resource Hierarchy for Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control) there's a gem at the very bottom:

> If you want to limit project creation in your Organization, change the [Organization access policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org) to grant the [Project Creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) to a group that you manage.

Specifically, the role you want to disinherit is *roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator*:

> Provides access to create new projects. Once a user creates a project, they're automatically granted the owner role for that project.

Comment: no idea why is this not by default... 

for these who are new to GCP and still can't figure out.

1) go to org [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?organizationId=[MY_ORG_ID]&project=&supportedpurview=project)
2) edit role of org member and remove Project Creator role

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is pretty old already, but the issue is still a valid one. To fix this in your GCP Org:

1. Select the Org in the console
2. Go to IAM & Admin > Manage Resources
3. Select the Org
4. Under Permissions, type "creator" to filter all other roles. You'll be left with "Billing account creator" and "Project Creator"
5. For both of these, make sure you have and are signed in as a principal that has these roles (in my example I have groups for "gcp-billing-admins@..." and "gcp-organization-admins@..."
6. You may see the Org icon and org name under each of these roles. Delete the org from each

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: Which tool did you use to make those callouts in your screenshot?

Comment: Skitch (https://evernote.com/products/skitch)